# MySQL: How to select values from one table and order by calculated values from a different table?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

Basically I have a table with comments:

```
id     target_item_id        comments
--------------------------------------
1      435                   blah blah
2      643                   blah blah
3      643                   blah blah
4      643                   blah blah
```

And a different, relational table with like and dislike votes for each comment:

```
id      comment_id          like
----------------------------------
1       2                   1
2       2                   1
3       2                   0
4       3                   1
5       3                   0
6       4                   1
```

`comment_id` on the second table relates to `id` on the first table. Basically I need a query that will select, for example, all comments for a specific `target_item` from the first table, but order the comments by popularity score. Popularity score is calculated by counting all likes (1s) and dislikes(0s) for a specific comment on the second table and subtracting the second result from the first. In this example, comment id 2 would have a popularity score of 1: count of likes (1s) is 2 and count of dislikes (0s) is 1: 2 - 1 = 1.

Would I be able, via MySQL, to create a query that will select the comments and order them by the popularity score in the fashion described above? Or would I have query each comment individually to acquire the score?

Hope it's clear enough to understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.id, c.target_item_id, c.comments,
       sum(case when v.`like`=1 then 1 when v.`like`=0 then -1 end) popularity
from comments c
left join votes v on v.comment_id = c.id
where c.target_item_id = 643
group by c.id, c.target_item_id, c.comments
order by popularity desc
```

Comment: Tried that but it is getting the SUM of all votes for the particular target_item instead of the SUM for each specific comment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you changed the dislike value from 0 to -1.  Then you could just Sum() the like column.